# Does XWiki Disable SSH?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssh, tomcat8, xwiki

I recently deployed an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance for a new intranet wiki. I installed java, tomcat, mySQL, and XWiki for this specifically.

I closed the SSH connection with PuTTY as I was setting up the XWiki and branding it appropriately but when I went to access it again, all I get is timeouts. SSH inbound rules are set to accept from all sources so I am almost certain it is not a network error, but I can't figure out what it is!

This has happened twice now, does anyone know of XWiki disallowing the ubuntu@ip.add.re.ss login with public key authentication?

Comment: I do not know much about the way AWS Deployment work, so just a generic idea: is it possible that on deploying a web server (like tomcat) AWS automatically sets up an extra firewall / security group that blocks the SSH port for everyone, including you?

Answer (score 0):

XWiki certainly does not do anything like this nor it could even if it wanted to if you installed tomcat properly (it's usually not supposed to run as root).

Comment: Ok thanks, that is what I thought, but can't seem to understand why when I install xwiki, it stops allowing ssh!

Comment: Maybe on a not very powerfull server a very active wiki could make the server so slow that the ssh server would not answer fast enough ? You could maybe try to modify a bit whatever start the application server to prefix the command like with "nice -n 10" for example to make sure the ssh server has an higher priority.